# Real time processes scheduling in Linux

Tags: kernel, process, scheduling

I have been learning some scheduling concepts. Currently my understanding so far is as below.

- There are real time processes and non real time processes.
- Non real time processes can have `nice` values for their priority in the range of **-20** to **+20**. The higher positive value indicates that the process has lower priority.
- The real time processes will have a niceness value listed as `-` as explained in this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127313/47538). This is mainly because the real time processes have higher priorities than the non real time processes and niceness value do not apply to them.
- Now, I can use `chrt` to see the real time attributes of a process.

For a real time process, the `chrt` gives output as,

```
chrt -p 5
pid 5's current scheduling policy: SCHED_FIFO
pid 5's current scheduling priority: 99
```

As we can see for process *5*, the priority is 99 which is the highest. Also, the scheduling policy is `SCHED_FIFO`

Now, for a non real time process, the `chrt` gives output as,

```
chrt -p 22383
pid 22383's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 22383's current scheduling priority: 0
```

As we can see for process *22383*, the priority is 0 and the scheduling policy is `SCHED_OTHER`.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible for me to make any process as real time process?
2. Is it possible for me to set some other scheduling algorithm other
   than `SCHED_OTHER` for a non real time process?
3. From [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-real-time-scheduling-priority-process/), I also see that I could modify the attribute for a
   running process as,

   ```
   chrt -p prio pid
   ```

   Also, I see `chrt -m` gives me the list of scheduling algorithms. The command gives me the output as,

   ```
   SCHED_OTHER min/max priority    : 0/0
   SCHED_FIFO min/max priority     : 1/99
   SCHED_RR min/max priority       : 1/99
   SCHED_BATCH min/max priority    : 0/0
   SCHED_IDLE min/max priority     : 0/0
   ```

   Now, as suggested above, if I set `chrt -p 55 22383` which algorithm will be used?

Comment: Static priority range 50-99 with real-time policy is a possible hazard. Default priority for hardware interrupts is 50. With RT sched, a task can only be interupted by a higher priority task or by voluntary yield/sleep (intermittent or short tasks). Eg. if you have an intensive calculation that will take 2 days and you set its sched priority to fifo 99 the computer will not respond until the task is complete 2 days later. With round-robin 99, p99 tasks will be rotated but nothing of lower priority will execute until all p99 are complete or sleeping.(¿Outcome from set both a fifo99 and a rr99?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Question 1**

It is possible for an user to use real time priority for a process as well. This configuration could be set from `/etc/security/limits.conf` file. I see the below contents in that file.

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
```

If we check the item section, we see the below entry which enables to set a real time priority for the users.

```
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
```

**Question 2 and Question 3**

To set scheduling policy to `SCHED_FIFO`, enter:

```
chrt -f -p [1..99] {pid}
```

To set scheduling policy to `SCHED_RR`, enter:

```
chrt -r -p [1..99] {pid}
```

So to answer question 3, we should verify the scheduling algorithms available and the priorities using the `chrt -m` command and then use any scheduling algorithm that suits our need. To set different priorities, we could use the commands as above.