# How to run real-time application in Linux?

Tags: debian, real-time

Trying to get working LinuxCNC on my Debian Jessie, I did:

- Installed the kernel 4.9 RT through Jessie backport using apt-get/aptitude.
- Restarted my computer and checked `uname -a` contain `PREEMPT RT`
- Installed LinuxCNC by adding the repository and using `apt-get`

After that, starting the linuxCNC wizard (by normal clicks through menus) there is a jitter test. My current results are absolutely bad, around 140us.

I wonder if there is any **PREEMPTION configuration to enable**, or specific way to **run an application** to get more precise real-time?

Also, how could I **check that the process is running real-time**?

Note: My computer is an intel E6600

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any PREEMPTION configuration to enable, or specific way to run an application to get more precise real-time?

See the following:

http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Latency-Test

which links to this:

https://forum.linuxcnc.org/18-computer/25927-reducing-latency-on-multicore-pc-s-success?limitstart=0

(from the above page:)

> Linux related changes:
>
> - edit /etc/default/grub and add the kernel options:  "isolcpus=1 acpi_irq_nobalance noirqbalance" (call update-grub afterwards)
> - make sure that the software "irqbalance" is NOT installed, remove if it is    there (Ubuntu software center -> installed software ->
>     search for    irqbalance -> remove)
> - add the upstart script "irq-affinity.conf" to    /etc/init (see attachments, it will move the irq-handling to the    first core)
> - add the sh scripts set-irq-affinity and watchirqs to    /usr/local/sbin (first allows to set the affinity mask manually, second opens a console 
>     window that shows live how the irqs are scheduled to the different cores
>     -> all numeric irqs but 0 should be handled by cpu0)

You might have to adapt the script for Système D, though ...

A quick thing to test:
You could also up the priority with `nice -n <x>`, where `<x>` is the desired priority.

> Also, how could I check that the process is running real-time?

See this question: [Real time processes scheduling in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154867/real-time-processes-scheduling-in-linux)

Comment: Regular `nice` priority isn't the same as real-time priority.